# Updating an object using a data which is coming from another component in angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, object, angular10

So in my project , I have 3 components. first is the main , secend and third.

I've created an empty object in the main component  and passed it into 2 others, and the secend component  make some changes and after all the 3rd component shows the changes in a table which is declared to show numbers.

I'm having trouble showing the updated value for `displayItmes ={}` in the third component.

I'm kind got stuck in here.

```
export class firstComponent{
  displayItems = {};
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-fill">
    <app-secend [displayItems]="displayItems"></app-secend>
    <app-third  [displayItems]="displayItems"></app-third>
</div>
```

The secend component is:

```
 export class secend {
    @Input() displayItems;
    x = _sum;
    syncDisplayItems() {
        this.displayItems.TotalPurchaseAndImport = 15 + x
    }
}
```

and the third component  is :

```
export class third {
    _displayItems;
    @Input()
    set displayItems(data: any) {
        if (data) {
            this._displayItems = data;
        }
    }

    get displayItems(): any {
        return this._displayItems;
    }
}
```

and the third component  HTML is:

```
<div class="p-col-3 vat-cell">
 {{ displayItems.TotalPurchaseAndImport}}
</div>
```

Comment: at the first HTML mark-up, you are referencing  first component from the first component. is it a typo on the question?

Comment: Not actually , i referencing the main component to the first

first = main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the secend component  `SyncDisplayItem` method that populate the data isn't called. try to implement `ngOnInit` and call it from there. I created a stack blitz solution with the same requirements and add extra button to demostrate the change event from second component `OnInit`and on Button click

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cgmkun?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fsecond.component.ts

Comment: I think there is a missundrestanding here. as i said. first component is the main component and by that i mean all html selectors should be in the appcomponent.

but i really liked your approuch. i did call the method in ngOnInit() but my data dont get updated.

Comment: if you could create a stackBlitz project it will be much helpful on solving the issue

Comment: Unfortunately this project is not open source that i can share it here. but no worries anymore. the problem solved.